# Array returns every item on every row instead of one item per row

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-recyclerview

I am trying to set a number of languages in a recycler view using a set which I converted into an array. I don't really understand why this results in every language being displayed on each row. Any pointers would be gratefully received. Here is my code:

```
    public void onInit(int initStatus) {
    if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        availableLanguages = myTTS.getAvailableLanguages();
        Locale[] arrayLocale = availableLanguages.toArray(new Locale[availableLanguages.size()]);
        String locDisplayResults = Arrays.toString(arrayLocale);

        for (int i = 1; i < arrayLocale.length; i++) {
            languagesList.add(new Language(arrayLocale[i], locDisplayResults));
            Collections.sort(languagesList, new Comparator<Language>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Language languages1, Language languages2) {
                    return languages1.getLocaleDisplay().compareTo(languages2.getLocaleDisplay());
                }
            });
            recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming languagesList is a Map, I don't know how you would think it would behave any differently given  String locDisplayResults = Arrays.toString(arrayLocale); and  languagesList.add(new Language(arrayLocale[i], locDisplayResults));

Comment: The thing is, I tried removing "arrayLocale[i]" and the same thing happens.

Comment: Do you know what Arrays.toString() does? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[]) You end up pulling the entire array. You'd be better to pull just the element you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code "Arrays.toString(arrayLocale);" will give you a string with all the elements. You are assigning this to the variable "locDisplayResults" and sets this on all lines in languagesList it seems. I think that is the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I understand but if I don't do that, this is what I get on each line: Ljava.util.Locale;@2884e86. Using String locDisplayResults = Arrays.toString(arrayLocale) allows me to get the actual languages, or at least the locales. I'll have to figure out how to get the display names after.

Comment: Have you tried this?
`languagesList.add(new Language(arrayLocale[i], arrayLocale[i].toString());`